# That's dog's feet

Tags: possessives, determiners, personal-pronouns

You see a set of feet of an animal, and someone asks you a question:

> What kind of animal has these feet?

Would all the following answers be correct, especially the ones with singular pronouns?

> 1. They/these are dog's feet.
> 2. That's dog's feet.
> 3. It's dog's feet.

Comment: Yup, they are all correct, in one dialect or tother. As well as *Them there's dog's feet.*

Comment: I wonder whether the saxon genitive is appropriate. I would just say "dog paws". Can anyone clarify that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question "what kind of animal has these feet?
 is

- **A dog**

The answer to "what kind of feet are these?" (a different question than the one you cited) is:

- "***Those*** are dog feet—but we call them paws."

Answer (score 0):

You would need a plural pronoun because you're referring to multiple feet. Only the first sentence would be correct.